# Angular Testing Debug Element Querying Yields null Sometimes - and Sometimes Not

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

So I have this component, which should show a green checkmark when clicked on as a standalone Angular component, and I like to test it e.g. with the following code:

```
 xit('should show check icon after click', () => {
  component.agendaItem = item1;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('li'));
  de.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const testEl = de.query(By.css('.fa.fa-check'));

  expect(component.selected).toBe(true);
  expect(testEl).toBeTruthy();
});
```

(I disabled the spec for now). The thing is, sometimes, the second element `testEl` is truthy, sometimes not, and I do not know under which circumstances. Also, I seems to sometimes have an impact on other unit tests, since the error also can get thrown in `afterAll()` again, not a consistent behavior and only occurring when I try and query the component's template.
I only have this error after switching to Angular 8, using Jasmine 3.4.0 and Karma 4.2.0 and it also disappears when I disable randomized testing by Jasmine.

Component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'm2m-agenda-item',
  template: `
      <li class="list-group-item mb-1" [class.m2m-agenda-item-selected]="selected" (click)="toggleSelect($event)">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div>
                  <h6>{{ agendaItem?.agendaItem }}</h6>
                  <br>
                  <p [innerHTML]="agendaItem?.agendaItemDescription"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                  <div><i *ngIf="selected" class="fa fa-check fa-lg text-secondary"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./find-invitation.scss']
})
export class AgendaItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() agendaItem;
  selected = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleSelect($event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.selected = !this.selected;
  }
}
```

and the test setup is as follows:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AgendaItemComponent]
  })
    .compileComponents();
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AgendaItemComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I usually used fakeAsync for tests including any events just to make sure the event is finished before continuing by using tick after the event was triggered and before fixture.detectChanges is triggered. Not too sure whether this will help in this case though but maybe it‘s worth a try.

Comment: I tried that as well. Thought it could be about timing. But still no success...

Comment: Are you able to recreate that issue in a stackblitz or is ut just too random?

Comment: did you solve that?